Three basic properties of radicals and when they fail?
Often you see these three properties grouped together with some sort of condition such that a, b, and n are all positive integers.
$$\sqrt[n]{a^n}=a$$
$$\sqrt[n]{ab}=\sqrt[n]{a}\cdot\sqrt[n]{b}$$
$$\sqrt[n]{(\frac{a}{b})}=\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}}{\sqrt[n]{b}}$$
But there's much more complexity to it than that, especially when imaginary numbers are allowed. I wanted to make a table, but I'm not sure if it's completely correct?


$\sqrt[n] {ab}=\sqrt[n]a\sqrt[n]b$ fails immediately for any complex number, regardless of n. Take $\frac{1}{i}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{-1}}=\sqrt{-1}=i$, but again $\frac{1}{i}=\frac{i}{i^2}=-i$ (The second one is correct actually)

Your example is showing $n=2$, $a=1$, $b=-1$. $\sqrt{\frac{1}{-1}}=\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{-1}}$ which would mean $i=\frac{1}{i}$. So in that sense that table IS wrong, but I think I was assuming that $\frac{a}{b}$ should be simplified first. I will add that qualifier.
